# How to make a date field to be autopopulated in Siebel CRM Desktop?

Tags: siebel

Whenever I create a new activity, I need a date field to be autopopulated ( it will be autopopulated but greyed out until and unless a checkbox next to it needs to be checked).

I perform a validation based on the date field, when a new activity is created. since the date field check box is not checked, it is not considering the value for the validation.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.
Jaya Vignesh.

Answer (score 0):

- make use of `predefault` and `postdefault` values to populate current-date.
- set field Read-only (BC field user property). You can find it under Business Component in object explorer.
- Field read-only allows you to make a field read-only based on value of other field from same BC or joined field.

> I perform a validation based on the date field, when a new activity is created. since the date field check box is not checked, it is not considering the value for the validation.

- This requirement of yours isn't clear what exactly you want to validate. Since you are populating it bydefault, I don't find the significance in validating your own auto-populated data. well yet I provide a suggestion below
- There are two types of validations, 1. Using configuration or 2. Using scripting. I am not pretty much sure if it can be achieved with configuration but scripting it is possible by overriding `BusComp_presetFieldValue`, `BusComp_preWriteValue`. The first one executed when you populate a field. And the latter one  when you commit the record.

I have answer assuming your requirement. Let me know if you have any questions or clarifications required.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Predefault property of the field to be the following
 System: TimeStamp